# race condition in Vector

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
1         if (!vector.contains(element))
2             vector.add(element);
```

the above code is not thread-safe because  race condition or    compound action happen in vector .

I don;t know how it happen

if a thread goes to line 1 and get a lock and  holding the lock then no other thread can obtain the lock  and call line 2 so where is race condition

is my understanding correct or did I miss some point ?
please explain in more details

Comment: Where's the lock in your code?  A vector is not a concurrent structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vector is thread safe in the sense it's methods are thread safe.  What you have is two separate calls to vector.  This means there is an issue for a race condition.

1. Thread A executes contains() and gets false
2. Thread B executes contains() and gets false
3. Thread A executes add and adds your element
4. Thread B executes add and adds your element again

To fix this you would need to synchronize the calls to the vector.  If this is the only area where the calls are done something like

```
synchronized(vector) {
    if(!vector.contains(element))
        vector.add(element);
}
```

Comment: And once you need to externally synchronize access, it may be better to use a non-synchronized type (such as ArrayList or HashSet) and use a Lock or ReadWriteLock to synchronize all access.

Comment: That is a very good point Brett.  At this point depending on the other code an ArrayList might be better.

Comment: Depending on the type/number of objects being added, the HashSet (or some other Set implementation) may be a good choice because of the contains call.